# Faster XORing of string

Tags: c#, xor

I was wondering if anyone knew of a faster way to XOR strings.

My current `DoXor()` function looks like this:

```
private string DoXor(byte[] s, string key)
{
    string outText = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<s.Length;)
    {
        for(int j = 0; (j<key.Length && i<s.Length); j++, i++)
        {
            outText += (char) (s[i] ^ key.ToCharArray()[j]);
            Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }

    return outText;
}
```

and it is immeasurably slow (longer than 2 minutes). For comparison, I am receiving data from a PHP script on my website, and it manages the XOR in <0.2 seconds, using the function

```
function doXor($string, $key = "magic_key") {

    // Our plaintext/ciphertext
    $text = $string;

    // Our output text
    $outText = '';

    // Iterate through each character
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); )
    {
        for($j=0; ($j<strlen($key) && $i<strlen($text)); $j++,$i++)
        {
            $outText .= $text{$i} ^ $key{$j};
            //echo 'i=' . $i . ', ' . 'j=' . $j . ', ' . $outText{$i} . '<br />'; // For debugging
        }
    }
    return $outText;
}
```

I am decrypting some data from a PHP script, encrypted by `base64_encode(doXor(base64_encode($data), $key))`, `$data` is the contents of a DLL file on disk, `$key` is the first 8 characters of an MD5 hash.

The data I am XORing has a size of roughly 2.5MB

Comment: An easy performance win might be to declare `key.ToCharArray()` as a variable outside of the loops. The content of it doesn't change, but you are making that call looped inside a loop right now.

Comment: You're also using `Console.WriteLine` within the loop - writing to the console is sloooow (comparatively speaking)

Comment: Strings are *text*. What do you expect XORing characters to do? Your current code XORs the UTF-16 code units, which could easily lead to unmapped characters. Fundamentally this feels like a very bad idea. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You can multi-thread your loop, but you will need to handle ordering

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I understand, I removed the `WriteLine` during my tests.

Comment: @nbokmans I have made this change now, lets see if it changes anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am "decrypting" some data from a PHP script, encrypted by `base64_encode(doXor(base64_encode($data), $key))`

Comment: It is *very* inefficient code, ToCharArray() must be hoisted out of the loop so it is only called once and the result should be stored in a StringBuilder.  To do it truly correctly and avoid the creepy consequences of a string not being able to store binary data, the result should be stored in byte[] and *then* encoded with Convert.ToBase64String().  How to properly XOR an 8-bit byte and a 16-bit char is up to you, strongly consider raising an exception when the char >= 256 since whatever app uses the result cannot possibly recover the original string.

Comment: Hmm... I'd try to move away from that approach to start with, if you possibly can. The code can definitely be optimized *and* made much more readable though...